# How can I avoid this infinite update loop in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component that has an `index` property in its state. When the index changes, I want it to pass new data to a child component in its props.

When the child component receives new data, I want it to make an AJAX call to update its own state. I cannot use `componentDidUpdate()` because this method runs when props or state changes. So, I basically get this happening:

1. Parent passes new props
2. Child runs `componentDidUpdate()`
3. Child runs `fetchFromServer()`, which updates state
4. Child runs `componentDidUpdate()`
5. To infinity...

**Is there a method for example that only runs when a component's props are updated?**

## Parent Component

```
export default class ResultsFrame extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      
      resultIndex: 0,

    }
  }

  render() {

    return (

        <SequenceView data={this.props.results.results[this.state.resultIndex]}/>

    );
  }
}
```

## Child Component

```
export default class SequenceView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: {},
      isLoading: true,
    }

  }

  render() {

    if(this.state.isLoading)
    {
      return ( <Spinner /> );
    }
    else
    {
      return (
        <div>

          {/* Render relevant stuff... */}

        </div>
      );
    }

  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    this.fetchFromServer();
  }

  componentDidUpdate()
  {
    this.fetchFromServer();
  }

  fetchFromServer = () =>
  {
    const sendData = {
      data: this.props.data,
    };

    axios.post(`/analysis/seqview`, sendData)
      .then(res => {
        const response = res.data;
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({data: response, isLoading: false});
      })
      .catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e.response.data.message);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: [`https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate`] has a bunch of parameters to check what exactly is different now. You can use that to prevent the infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation

**You may call setState() immediately in componentDidUpdate() but note that it must be wrapped in a condition like in the example above, or you’ll cause an infinite loop.**

This is exactly what you are doing here . your componentDidUpdate calls `fetchFromServer` which sets the state .

You need to change your componentDidUpdate to

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.data.something !== prevProps.data.something) {
    this.fetchFromServer();
  }
}
```

**Refer:**

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: Thank you sir. Sorry, I am not sure how I didn't come across this page. I think I learned about the method through a blog post, and should have checked the docs. It works now!!